# PendingIntent opens main activity instead of desired activity

Tags: android

I am creating an android application that shows a notification in a Service.

I show the notification exactly as mentioned in [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html). It works fine and the PendingItent object starts the desired activity.

But after **a while** when I close and restart the application a couple of times, tapping on the notification will start the **Main Activity** (which is the parent of desired activity) instead of the desired activity.

The only way I found to fix that is to restart the device. (Clearing app's cache and uninstalling didn't help.

I googled my problem and also searched here a lot, but couldn't find anything relevant. 
seems that I'm the only one having this problem.

Could anyone please help me with this problem?

Thanks in advance;

**EDIT:**

as I said, I do exactly like the documentation. But here is my code anyway:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MyActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = 
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("Body");

    builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(457, builder.build());
```

Comment: Interesting, can you share the code creating the pending intent?

Comment: I'm joining to question, since I face with same situation, but bit simpler code:

    Intent intent = new Intent("show_reminder_dialog_action");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, entryId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =  new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);